# Setting default webapp using docBase

Tags: url, tomcat, web-applications

I have configured the Tomcat Catalina context as below to set **appA** as the default docBase.

```xml
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">    
  <Context  path="" docBase="appA"/>
</Host>
```

With this setup, I am able to access `webapps/appA/js/test.js` by hitting

```
http://localhost/js/test.js
```

The problem I am facing and not able to understand is: when I have multiple apps under the webapps folder (`webapps/appB`, `webapps/appC`), I am able to access

```
http://localhost/appA/js/test.js
```

like this. But this is not working if I have only one app under webapps (`webapps/appA`).

I've read Tomcat documentation on this property, but I couldn't find am answer. Could someone help me understand `docBase`?